# How to trunc or cast datetime to date in load data from csv in an Oracle 11g table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I need to convert an incoming Datetime that is formatted like this `2/5/2010 12:00:00 AM` and it has to go into the table as `"MM/DD/YYYY"`. I have been researching and I cant find what syntax to use to either cast or trunc my incoming Datetime. I get this error

```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 11.
Expecting "," or ")", found "(".
,   trunc(EXAMPLE_DATE)            DATE "MM/DD/YYYY" NULLIF (EXAMPLE_DATE
```

when I try to use this code

```
OPTIONS (READSIZE=20971520, BINDSIZE=20971520, ROWS=10000, ERRORS=90000)
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE EXAMPLE.TABLE
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    EXAMPLE1                CHAR NULLIF (EXAMPLE1=BLANKS)
,   EXAMPLE2                CHAR NULLIF (EXAMPLE2=BLANKS)
,   trunc(EXAMPLE_DATE)     DATE "MM/DD/YYYY" NULLIF (EXAMPLE_DATE=BLANKS)
)
```

I've tried using to_date, trunc, and to_char, but I'm not quite sure which to use, and what syntax to use it in. Clearly I cant trunc the `EXAMPLE_DATE` as I am attempting to.

EDIT:
The original code looks like this

```
OPTIONS (READSIZE=20971520, BINDSIZE=20971520, ROWS=10000, ERRORS=90000)
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE EXAMPLE.TABLE
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    EXAMPLE1                CHAR NULLIF (EXAMPLE1=BLANKS)
,   EXAMPLE2                CHAR NULLIF (EXAMPLE2=BLANKS)
,   EXAMPLE_DATE        DATE "MM/DD/YYYY" NULLIF (EXAMPLE_DATE=BLANKS)
)
```

This code works as expected with a csv file with only dates in the `MM/DD/YYYY` format, but when given a Datetime that looks like this: `2/5/2010 12:00:00 AM` it will output a `.bad` file in the directory of the csv.

Comment: I'm confused.  A `date` column in Oracle supports a time component.  What problem do you have inserting the value as is (with the right format specification, of  course)?

Comment: I just get a `.bad` file, without any further error messages, but when I go and manually edit the file to change the Datetime to simply just a `"MM/DD/YYY"` date, the upload works without error.

Comment: You shouldn't have any SQL function around the field name. Why do you have the date format as `"MM/DD/YYYY"` instead of the actual format in the file, `"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM"`? (Assuming the original data is MM/DD, not DD/MM...)

Comment: I get a `.bad` file either way, with the `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM` or the `MM/DD/YYYY`. This csv dump used to come to me to be uploaded with dates strictly in `MM/DD/YYYY` format, but the person sending it has changed and they started sending it as a Datetime. I inherited this control file, and I just wanted to try to get it to work instead of asking them to change their query for their dump

Comment: the example_date column in your table is of what data type?

Comment: It works with the date in that format in the data, and the format I referred to before in the control file. What error did you get in the log when you tried that?

Comment: if you use SQL Developer, we'll look at your CSV and do the mapping for you - even for SQLLDR https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/using-oracle-sql-developer-to-setup-sqlloader-runs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the format in your control file to match the value you're getting in your data file:

```
,   EXAMPLE_DATE        DATE "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM" NULLIF (EXAMPLE_DATE=BLANKS)
```

I set a table to match your example:

```
create table example_table (example1 varchar2(10), example2 varchar2(10), example_date date);
```

And a data file containing:

```
A,B,2/5/2010 12:00:00 AM
```

And a control file as:

```
OPTIONS (READSIZE=20971520, BINDSIZE=20971520, ROWS=10000, ERRORS=90000)
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE EXAMPLE_TABLE
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    EXAMPLE1                CHAR NULLIF (EXAMPLE1=BLANKS)
,   EXAMPLE2                CHAR NULLIF (EXAMPLE2=BLANKS)
,   EXAMPLE_DATE        DATE "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM" NULLIF (EXAMPLE_DATE=BLANKS)
)
```

Running that through reported:

```
Commit point reached - logical record count 1
```

and the log file said:

```
Table EXAMPLE_TABLE:
  1 Row successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
```

and the table was populated with that data:

```
select * from example_table;

EXAMPLE1   EXAMPLE2   EXAMPLE_DA
---------- ---------- ----------
A          B          2010-02-05
```

---

You also said:

> it has to go into the table as "MM/DD/YYYY"

It has to go into the table as a date. A date doesn't have any intrinsic human-readable format; Oracle uses its own internal representation to store data efficiently and unambiguously. When you query the table your client will convert that to a recognisable format for display, using either its own settings or your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. If you're seeing the dates in the format you showed then that is what you client/session is set to display them as. Mine is configured as YYYY-MM-DD, so that's what you see in the output from my query above.

Comment: This works. I took your date format and did some spot checking by copying only a thousand or so rows at a time, and it works on 90% of the .csv data dump file (which is 32K rows). However it was still giving me a `.bad` when I ran the entire file. I edited the file and removed all Datetimes changing all dates to `MM/DD/YYYY`, and it ran fine. So my assumption is that there is a formatting error in ~10% of the Datetimes. Maybe a day when I'm bored I'll try to find out what the difference is between those 3.2K rows and all the rest. At a glance they appear to be formatted correctly.